# Consequences of living on either of two habitable planets orbiting a super-Earth?

Tags: planets, habitability, rogue-planets

I'm working on a habitable planetary system just at the doorstep of the Solar System. I'd like it to be unique, so I'm thinking of using two habitable planets orbiting a super-Earth. The super-Earth is four times the size of Earth.

What consequences could be expected living on either of the two habitable planets?

Comment: First, when you say 4 times the size, do you mean 4 times the radius or 4 times the mass? The problem you'll run into in either case is the '3 body problem'. Two body's have pretty stable orbits, 3 bodies need special circumstances in order for the orbits to be stable. [Weird Orbits - the three body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem) I think you'd be better off with a gas giant, a super-Jupiter than a super-Earth. Then you'd be in better shape for stability. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitable_exomoon So unless you've found a quirky solution to the 3 body problem fo

Comment: Hello CuriousMoron, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Does your definition of "super earth" match [NASA's definition](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/what-is-an-exoplanet/planet-types/super-earth/)? Can we assume "four times the size" means 4X the mass and not 4X the volume? What is the size of the two orbiting moons (planet-sized or not, they're moons of the super earth)? Finally, just how far away is the "doorstep of the Solar System" because if you're too far away, the Sun won't warm the moons enough to be habitable. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is the super-earth orbiting sun? What is the energy source of these planets? If it is sun, then it is far away. Are these planets rocky? Do they have an atmosphere? What is the source of oxygen? Can plants grow there?

Comment: How far away is the super-earth from its sun? How big are you expecting your habitable moons to be? There are tight constraints on your system based on those two variables. There are lots of questions about [habitable exomoons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=habitable+exomoon) for you to look at, but unless the "super earth" is a gas giant then you're going to run into difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer in two phases - first, what kind of life might be native to the moons, and then second, what humans might do if they wanted to terraform or colonize these moons.

So, you have two planet-sized moons around a much bigger planet, all in the habitable zone of a star system. The super-earth they orbit is probably not habitable, for any number of reasons (those we have been able to observe seem to be covered in active volcanoes and lava flow), but what about the moons? Because of their orbit around the planet, their access to sunlight will vary. This could have several consequences.

Probably the outside of the planet would be ice. I don't have the math to back this up, but my gut tells me that if earth, with constant access to the sun, has had periods of its history where large portions of it froze over, then a planet without that constant access would probably not be able to support a consistent warm surface atmosphere.

Similarly, if earth has had lots of extinction events in its evolutionary history without sunlight being a major variable, making sunlight disappear sometimes would almost certainly mean more die-offs. This doesn't mean there wouldn't be life, but it could mean the life forms are more simple. I don't imagine a planet like this would support multi-cellular life. Again, this is just a gut call, but I feel like we're talking about all microbes. Life could develop on the surface, but have to adapt strategies for surviving long periods of cold. Life could also develop underwater, in patches of warm water carved out of the ice by volcanic activity. On earth, microorganisms capable of surviving such extreme environments exist - on this planet, I think they would be the foundation of most life.

Now - what could humans do with a planet like this?

If they wanted to make the surface of the planet more resemble the surface of earth, it would be difficult, but not impossible. The obvious solution, of course, is domed cities that maintain an internal atmosphere through artificial light and heat sources. These could be built on the surface or underwater.

How would the native life interfere with human domes? Once the domes were constructed, oxygen in the atmosphere would probably present a powerful protection to any potential pathogens. Even if they could survive extreme heat or extreme cold, oxygen kills a lot of microbes. The human body, however, offers many oxygen-free habitats, some of which might actually be similar to warm underwater ocean environments. If, during construction, some alien microbes managed to attach themselves to the insides of structures and stayed there, its not impossible to imagine them becoming a problem later - especially when one considers that, in the evolutionary history of a planet that is away from the sun for long periods of time, some kind of stasis or dormancy is probably a part of their life cycle. So, humans might not realize that they've taken on invasive pathogens until they've already spread them.

I've kind of run away with your question, but maybe this helps?